# Javascript trying to write function to increment and return second number for every amount of 25 past set amount of first number

Tags: javascript

I have a word count function that returns the number of words in a string.

Now I'm trying to add to that function to count, by increments of 25, how many words over 50 there are then increase a second number based on that outcome, but I'm stumped on how to set that second number

```
const setHeight = (bodyText) => {
  bodyText = bodyText.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
  bodyText = bodyText.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
  bodyText = bodyText.replace(/\n /,"\n");

  let bodyTextLength = bodyText.split(' ').length;

  let height = 400;

  // Not sure how to accomplish the counting here, added pseudo code for context

  for(let i = 50; bodyLength > i; i++){
    ...let height = number
  }

  return height
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your solution could look something like this:

```
let wordCount = 78;
let over50 = 78 - 50; // 28
let incrementsOf25 = Math.ceil(over50 / 25); // divide by 25 and round up
```

Then you could modify height by whatever amount is necessary per increment of 25. Let me know if I misunderstood!